# Spring boot project gives org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHandle at the start

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Although that I can see `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHandle` exists in the Maven Repository, I get the this error when I run `App.java`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHandle
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

These are the dependencies in my `pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- hibernate-validator was added to stop an error when starting the server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you try to do run maven clean install?

Comment: Do `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` then rebuild the artifact... This will force a fresh download of the jars

Comment: @kkflf that didn't work. but what M. Deinum said worked.

Comment: Perfect! Good luck with your project